# Propriedade de um método em outro método

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, método

Tenho pesquisado sobre o problema, mas não consegui solucionar. Estou começando com PHP orientado a objetos e estou com uma dúvida

```
class Correios{
    public $nome_do_user;

        public function RecebeJson(){
            $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $dados = json_decode($json, TRUE);
            $this->nome_do_user = $dados['message']['from']['first_name'];
        }       

        public function getUser(){
            $this->nome_do_user;
        }

        public function viewthis(){
            var_dump($this);
        }

}   

$correios = new Correios();
$correios->getUser();
$correios->viewthis();
```

Ou seja: Recebo um JSON com o nome do usuário e armazeno em `$this->nome_do_user`. Porém, desejo chama-lo no método `getUser`, mas neste método, `nome_do_user` já não existe mais no `$this` (percebi via `var_dump`).

Logo, quando o chamo via `getUser`, nada é retornado

Onde estou errando? Defini a propriedade no primeiro método, porque ele não passa pro segundo?

Comment: Você não está chamando o método `RecebeJson` antes de chamar `getUser`. Ai a variavel não existe ainda mesmo. Se quer que esteja disponivel na criação do objeto, crie um construtor(`__construct(){}`) e inicie nele o método RecebeJSON.

Comment: Fiz desta forma, criei um contrutor e nele chama RecebeJson..Depois tentei exibir o usuário via $correios->getUser();, mas mesmo assim ainda não foi...

Comment: Em php o construtor é um método previamente definido como `function __construct(){}`.

Comment: Sim, exatamente como fiz....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é viável tentar corrigir o código que postou pois OOP é conceitual e depende de como está a estrutura dos outros códigos do sistema que está a desenvolver.

No código que postou há o clássico *getter* do `getter and setter` (termo popular). O nome técnico é "accessors and mutators".

No entanto, está aplicado de forma redundante, pois a propriedade `nome_do_user` está definida como pública. Ou seja, pode ser acessada livremente sem *accessors* ou pode ser modificada livremente sem *mutators*.

```
$correios = new Correios();
var_dump($correios->nome_do_user);
```

Para corrigir e chegar a um caminho mais adequado na programação orientada a objetos, procure entender o básico que é a definição de visibilidade das propriedades e métodos: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

## Exemplo com accessors e mutators (getter and setter)

Retornando ao código, mesmo que invoque `$correios->nome_do_user`, ainda assim não obterá nada de `nome_do_user` pois não foi setado.

Para setar, invoque o método `RecebeJson()` antes de acessar `nome_do_user`:

```
$correios = new Correios();
$correios->RecebeJson();
var_dump($correios->nome_do_user);
```

Ok, funcionou! Mas não resolveu nada em OOP propriamente falando.

```
class Correios
{

    /*
    Definimos com visibilidade privada, para que seja acessível somente dentro desse objeto Correios.
    */
    private $nome_do_user = null;

    public function setNomeUser()
    {
        /*
        Uma condicional que verifica se está vazio. Isso evita executar a rotina mais de uma vez.
        A lógica aqui é que se já foi executado, provavelmente não precisa executar mais vezes pois apenas estaria consumindo processos.
        */
        if ($this->nome_do_user === null) {
            $this->nome_do_user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        }
    }

    /*
    Accessor que retorna a propriedade nome_do_user.
    */
    public function getNomeUser()
    {
        return $this->nome_do_user;
    }

}

$correios = new Correios();
$correios->setNomeUser();
var_dump($correios->getNomeUser());
```

Como pode ver, na prática, muita coisa foi modificada do original.

## Exemplo suprimindo o mutator (setter)

Falando pessoalmente, apesar da tentativa em demonstrar um jeito de corrigir, eu me sinto incomodado pois não quer dizer que isso seja correto ou o melhor a se fazer, pois como comentei no início, OOP é conceitual. É um conjunto de paradigmas. Mas não vamos entrar nessa discussão pois é algo muito extenso. Vamos então a uma nova sugestão de melhorar, ou otimizar essa classe:

O que me incomoda nessa classe é que parece não fazer sentido o uso de um *mutator*. Nesse caso `setNomeUser()`. Podemos simplificar assim:

```
class Correios
{

    /*
    Definimos com visibilidade privada, para que seja acessível somente dentro desse objeto Correios.
    */
    private $nome_do_user = null;

    public function getNomeUser()
    {
        /*
        Uma condicional que verifica se está vazio. Isso evita executar a rotina mais de uma vez.
        A lógica aqui é que se já foi executado, provavelmente não precisa executar mais vezes pois apenas estaria consumindo processos.
        */
        if ($this->nome_do_user === null) {
            $this->nome_do_user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        }
        return $this->nome_do_user;
    }

}

$correios = new Correios();
var_dump($correios->getNomeUser());
```

Ainda assim isso pode não ser o ideal para o seu projeto, pois depende do planejamento, do que mais pretende implementar nessa classe.

Apesar disso, note que agora saímos do padrão "getter and setter" (accessor and mutator) e estamos criando um novo padrão.

Os pontos que deve observar é, o padrão conceitual que está criando é algo existente, reconhecido e aceito amplamente pelas comunidades de desenvolvedores?

Mesmo que seja um padrão diferente dos padrões já existentes e amplamente reconhecidos, posso criar um padrão próprio?

Desde que esteja bem documentado, sim. E obviamente desde que seja coerente, e bem escrito.

## Exemplo com constructors

Vamos a um terceiro exemplo de como "refinar" ou "complicar" o que já é complicado.

```
class Correios
{

    /*
    Definimos com visibilidade privada, para que seja acessível somente dentro desse objeto Correios.
    */
    private $nome_do_user = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        /*
        Uma condicional que verifica se está vazio. Isso evita executar a rotina mais de uma vez.
        A lógica aqui é que se já foi executado, provavelmente não precisa executar mais vezes pois apenas estaria consumindo processos.
        */
        if ($this->nome_do_user === null) {
            $this->nome_do_user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getNomeUser()
    {
        return $this->nome_do_user;
    }

}

$correios = new Correios();
var_dump($correios->getNomeUser());
```

Na prática, faz o mesmo que o segundo exemplo. A diferença é que usamos o método construtor. `__construct()`.

O método `__construct()` é invocado automaticamente sempre que inicia uma nova instância de uma classe.

Ou seja, sempre que fizer `$var = new NomeDaClasse()`, caso exista um método chamado `__construct()`, este será executado automaticamente. Consulte: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

## Métodos estáticos

Agora vamos "radicalizar" e mostrar essa coisa toda com métodos estáticos.

```
class Correios
{
    private static $nome_do_user = null;
    public static getNomeUser()
    {
        /*
        Uma condicional que verifica se está vazio. Isso evita executar a rotina mais de uma vez.
        A lógica aqui é que se já foi executado, provavelmente não precisa executar mais vezes pois apenas estaria consumindo processos.
        */
        if (self::$nome_do_user === null) {
            self::$nome_do_user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        }
        return self::$nome_do_user;
    }
}

var_dump(Correios::getNomeUser());
```

Quando usar métodos e propriedades estáticas?

A coisa que parecia simples vai se aprofundando em assuntos muito complexos.

Você pode pensar que é muito mais limpo visualmente invocar `Correios::getNomeUser();` ao invés de

```
$correios = new Correios();
$correios->getNomeUser();
```

Afinal, se posso chegar ao mesmo resultado com um código menor, é esse que devo usar?

Performaticamente, o estilo estático é melhor que instanciar um objeto?

A cada pergunta, você vai provavelmente criar novas perguntas. Por isso a complexidade em orientá-lo o quê ou qual o caminho correto a seguir.

## Consideração final

Apesar das críticas e conselhos nas respostas existentes e comentários, não desanime. Todo bom programador começou como você, escrevendo códigos conceituais sem saber o que exatamente estava fazendo. Com o tempo, praticando muito e estudando, você conseguirá entender como usar de forma adequada.

Eu ainda poderia demonstrar mais umas 5 formas diferentes, mas acredito que até aqui seja o suficiente para que você entenda e escolha o que realmente quer usar. Mas concordo com o que citaram. Evite usar coisas mirabulantes do OOP se você não entender o que está fazendo. Num resumo, procure o passo básico que é a definição de visibilidade (public, protected, private).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Vou ler com atenção sobre visibilidade. Valeu!

Answer (score 3):

## Algumas considerações

OOP por si só não resolve problema algum. Muitos casos onde se fica tentando usar OOP ficaria melhor sem este paradigma. Saber o que está fazendo, pensar sobre o problema, entender os requisitos e aplicá-los corretamente no código é que faz a diferença. Todo mundo que diz que OOP faz isso ou aquilo está vendendo uma ideia. Fazer OOP ou de outro jeito certo é que fará o código ficar bom.

É estranho ter `$nome_do_user` público e ter um método para pegar seu valor, parece redundante. Pode ser que exista um motivo no futuro, mas ainda não está claro quando usar um ou outro para pegar o nome do usuário. Mas se vai usar OOP (não estou dizendo que deva), os atributos deveriam ser privados e serem acessados por algum método.

Usar um membro não inicializado será um problema mesmo.

Criar alguma forma de acesso à algo que não está garantidamente inicializado não é OOP ou qualquer outra coisa, é programação errada. Um objeto não deve ter um estado transitório. Pode ser que um dia isto possa evoluir e mostrar a necessidade de uma classe, mas no momento só está causando confusão. Seria tão mais simples ter uma função que faz o que tem que fazer, retorna um resultado e pronto.

## A solução

Se ainda quiser insistir nisto tem que garantir que o estado está válido antes de usar. Se não estiver tem que informar isto, sei lá, talvez lançando uma exceção. Mas não vejo isto com bons olhos, continua parecendo programação errado, parece solução artificial porque está usando a ferramenta errada.

Uma solução um pouco melhor seria ter um construtor que garantisse que ou tem o estado do objeto em ordem ou não criar o objeto. Neste caso específico continua parecendo gambiarra, mas é um pouco melhor porque pode evitar a exceção. Não adianta criar um construtor e ele deixar o objeto ser criado quando há problemas durante a criação.

Note que [o código funciona](http://ideone.com/FDmHVU) quando usado corretamente (OOP está criando dificuldade ao invés de facilidade), ainda que precisei organizar e fazer alguns ajustes. Por exemplo faltava um `return` no método `getUser()`. Eu poderia ter feito outras mudanças. Acho curioso a mistura de português com inglês. O próprio nome da classe não parece refletir o que ela faz. Pode parecer bobo mas estas coisas indicam que a classe está sendo montada sem pensar. OOP também tem muito a ver com dar nomes corretos para cada coisa. E espero que `viewthis()` esteja aí só temporariamente para um teste.

O problema deste código é que existe uma situação que o resultado não é o esperado, o que sempre pode acontecer e esta situação não está sendo tratada adequadamente. Quando algo falha, o código precisa refletir isto.

## Conclusão

Eu não vou tentar refazer esta classe para ficar certa, porque ela como um todo é a ferramenta errada. Não gosto de ensinar fazer algo que no fundo está errado só para agradar um gosto.

Insisto que uma função simples que retornasse o resultado ou um valor nulo se não for possível dar um resultado seria o suficiente.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ótima explanação. Estou começando agora meus estudos em POO e já tinha notado alguns dos pontos que você citou. Sem orientação a objetos, eu já o teria feito, mas preferi desta forma para treinar meu aprendizado. Costumo fazer essa mistura de português com inglês as vezes, mas não o faria se o código não fosse só meu, rs...E sim, vou remover o viewthis kkk. Bom, o código agora funciona, percebi onde estava errando, tentando usar uma var ainda não chamada e esqueci um return... Muito obrigado a todos !